# Unfortunately, (App Name) has stopped in eclipse

Tags: java, javascript, android, xml, eclipse

when I press on any button on the application this appears " Unfortunately , (App Name) has stopped". I am using eclipse.
I use another similar [project]: http://android.okhelp.cz/dw/Calculator.apk and I change something. The original project works but this one not
http://android.okhelp.cz/calculator-open-source/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="130dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:cursorVisible="false"
        android:gravity="right"
       />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_sin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickListener_sin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="sin" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_cos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClickListener_cos"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="cos" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_del"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1.40"
        android:onClick="onClickListenerReset"
        android:text="Delete" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_tan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickListener_tan"
        android:text="tan" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickListener7"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickListener8"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.00"
        android:onClick="onClickListener9"
        android:text="9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.00"
        android:onClick="onClickListenerDivide"
        android:text="/" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_log"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickListener_log"
        android:text="log" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickListener4"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickListener5"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.00"
        android:onClick="onClickListener6"
        android:text="6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.00"
        android:onClick="onClickListenerMultiply"
        android:text="*" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_bra1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickListener_bra1"
        android:text="(" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickListener1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickListener2"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.00"
        android:onClick="onClickListener3"
        android:text="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonMinus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1.00"
        android:onClick="onClickListenerMinus"
        android:text="-" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_bra2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickListener_bra2"
        android:text=")" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPoint"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickListenerPoint"
        android:text="." />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickListener0"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonEqual"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickListenerEqual"
        android:text="="
        android:textSize="15sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPlus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="onClickListenerPlus"
        android:text="+"
        android:textSize="15dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The jave file

```
package calc.pack;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText editText;

Button button0,button1,button2,button3,
       button4,button5,button6,button7,button8,button9,buttonPlus,buttonMinus,buttonMultiply,
            buttonDivide,buttonEqual,buttonPoint,buttonDel,buttonReset,
            button_sin,button_cos,button_tan,button_del,button_bra1,button_bra2,button_reset;

String sum="",one,two,three,four,five,
                        six,seven,eight,nine,
                        zero,plus,minus,multiply,divide,equal,point,del,reset,bra1,bra2;

Integer countOne=0;

Float result=0f,result_mul=1f,result_div=1f;

int pressCount=1,sumZero,c,i;

char press;

String EditTextMsg;

Float floatEditTextMsg;

Double after_log,doubleEditTextMsg,afterSin,after_cos,after_tan,toRadian_doubleEditTextMsg;

Vibrator vibrator;
Bundle savedInstanceState;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    button0=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button0);
    button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button4);

    button5=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    button6=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);
    button7=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button7);
    button8=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button8);
    button9=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button9);

    buttonPlus=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
    buttonMinus=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMinus);
    buttonMultiply=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonMultiply);
    buttonDivide=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonDivide);
    buttonPoint=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonPoint);

    buttonEqual=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonEqual);

    button_sin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sin);
    button_cos=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_cos);
    button_tan=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_tan);

    button_del=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_del);

    vibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); 


    editText.setText(result.toString());


}
public void onClickListener0(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);
    if(press=='=')
    {
        onClickListenerReset(buttonReset);
    }

    if(sum !="")
    {
        zero=(String)button0.getText();

        sum=sum+zero;
        editText.setText(sum);
    }
    else
    {
        sum="0";
        editText.setText("0");
    }
}

public void onClickListener1(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);

    if(press=='=')
    {
        onClickListenerReset(buttonReset);
    }

    one=(String)button1.getText();
    sum=sum+one;

    editText.setText(sum);
}

public void onClickListener2(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);

    if(press=='=')
    {
        onClickListenerReset(buttonReset);
    }

    if(press=='=')
    {
        onClickListenerEqual(buttonEqual);
    }

    two=(String)button2.getText();
    sum=sum+two;

    editText.setText(sum);
}

public void onClickListener3(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);
    if(press=='=')
    {
        onClickListenerReset(buttonReset);
    }
    three=(String)button3.getText();
    sum=sum+three;

    editText.setText(sum);
}

public void onClickListener4(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);

    if(press=='=')
    {
        onClickListenerReset(buttonReset);
    }

    four=(String)button4.getText();
    sum=sum+four;

    editText.setText(sum);
}

public void onClickListener5(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);
    if(press=='=')
    {
        onClickListenerReset(buttonReset);
    }

    five=(String)button5.getText();
    sum=sum+five;

    editText.setText(sum);
}

public void onClickListener6(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);
    if(press=='=')
    {
        onClickListenerReset(buttonReset);
    }

    six=(String)button6.getText();
    sum=sum+six;

    editText.setText(sum);
}

public void onClickListener7(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);
    if(press=='=')
    {
        onClickListenerReset(buttonReset);
    }

    seven=(String)button7.getText();
    sum=sum+seven;

    editText.setText(sum);
}

public void onClickListener8(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);
    if(press=='=')
    {
        onClickListenerReset(buttonReset);
    }

    eight=(String)button8.getText();
    sum=sum+eight;

    editText.setText(sum);
}

public void onClickListener9(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);
    if(press=='=')
    {
        onClickListenerReset(buttonReset);
    }

    nine=(String)button9.getText();
    sum=sum+nine;

    editText.setText(sum);
}

public void onClickListenerPlus(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);

    if(press=='-')
    {
        onClickListenerEqual(buttonMinus);
    }
    else if(press=='*')
    {
        onClickListenerEqual(buttonMultiply);
    }

    else if(press=='/')
    {
        onClickListenerEqual(buttonDivide);
    }


    press='+';

    if(sum != "")
    {
        result=result+Float.parseFloat(editText.getText().toString());

        editText.setText(result.toString());

        result_mul=result;

        result_div=result;

        sum="";            
    }
    else
    {
        editText.setText(result.toString());

        result_mul=result;

        result_div=result;

        sum="";
    }

}

public void onClickListenerMinus(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);
    if(press=='+')
    {
        onClickListenerEqual(buttonPlus);
    }
    else if(press=='*')
    {
        onClickListenerEqual(buttonMultiply);
    }
    else if(press=='/')
    {
        onClickListenerEqual(buttonDivide);
    }



    press='-';

    EditTextMsg= editText.getText().toString(); 
    floatEditTextMsg=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

    if(sum==""  && result==0)
    {
        sum=sum+'-';
        //Log.d("sum=","minus press");
    }
    else if(sum != "")
    {
        if(result==0)
        {
            result=Float.parseFloat(sum)-result;

            editText.setText(result.toString());

            result_mul=result;

            result_div=result;

            sum="";
        }

        else
        {
            result=result-Float.parseFloat(sum);

            editText.setText(result.toString());

            result_mul=result;

            result_div=result;

            sum="";
        }
    }

}

public void onClickListenerMultiply(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);
    if(press=='/')
    {
        onClickListenerEqual(buttonDivide);
    }
    else if(press=='+')
    {
        onClickListenerEqual(buttonPlus);
    }

    else if(press=='-')
    {
        onClickListenerEqual(buttonMinus);
    }



    press='*';

    EditTextMsg= editText.getText().toString(); 
    floatEditTextMsg=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

    if(sum !="")
    {
        result_mul=result_mul * floatEditTextMsg; 

        result=result_mul;

        result_div=result_mul;

        editText.setText(result_mul.toString());

        sum="";
    }
    else
    {
        editText.setText(EditTextMsg);

        //result_mul=result_mul * Float.parseFloat(sum);

        //result=result_mul;

        sum="";
    }

}


public void onClickListenerDivide(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);
    if(press=='+')
    {
        onClickListenerEqual(buttonPlus);
    }

    else if(press=='-')
    {
        onClickListenerEqual(buttonMinus);
    }

    else if(press=='*')
    {
        onClickListenerEqual(buttonMultiply);
    }

    press='/';

    EditTextMsg= editText.getText().toString(); 
    floatEditTextMsg=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

    if(sum !="" && result_div==1)
    {
        //int c=0;

        if(c==0)
        {
            result_div=floatEditTextMsg/result_div;  
            Log.d("if if result_div=", result_div.toString());
            c++;
        }
        else
        {
            result_div=result_div/floatEditTextMsg; 
            Log.d("if else result_div=", result_div.toString());
        }


        result=result_div;
        result_mul=result_div;

        editText.setText(result_div.toString());

        sum="";
    }
    else if(sum !="" && result_div !=1)
    {
        result_div=result_div/floatEditTextMsg; 

        Log.d("else if result_div=", result_div.toString());

        result=result_div;

        result_mul=result_div;

        editText.setText(result_div.toString());

        sum="";
    }
    else
    {
        editText.setText(EditTextMsg);

        sum="";
    }
}



public void onClickListenerPoint(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);

   int error=0;

    if(sum !=null)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<sum.length();i++)
        {
            if(sum.charAt(i)=='.')
            {
                error=1;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    if(error==0)
    {
        if(sum==null)
        {
            sum=sum+"0.";
        }
        else
        {
            sum=sum+".";
        }
    }

    editText.setText(sum);
}

public void onClickListenerEqual(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);

    if(press=='+') 
    {
        onClickListenerPlus(buttonPlus);
        //msg1= editText.getText().toString(); 
        //floatMsg=Float.parseFloat(msg1);
    }
    else if(press=='-') 
    {
        onClickListenerMinus(buttonMinus);
    }
    else if(press=='*') 
    {
        onClickListenerMultiply(buttonMultiply);
    }
    else if(press=='/')
    {
        onClickListenerDivide(buttonDivide);
    }

    press='=';


}



public void onClickListenerReset(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);

    sum="";
    countOne=0;//result=0;

    result=0f;
    result_mul=1f;
    result_div=1f;
    press=' ';
    c=0;

    editText.setText(result.toString());
}


public void onClickListener_sin(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);

    EditTextMsg= editText.getText().toString(); 
    doubleEditTextMsg=Double.parseDouble(EditTextMsg);//degree

    toRadian_doubleEditTextMsg=Math.toRadians(doubleEditTextMsg);

    afterSin =Math.sin(toRadian_doubleEditTextMsg);

    editText.setText(afterSin.toString());

    EditTextMsg=editText.getText().toString();
    result=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

    result_mul=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

    result_div=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);


    sum="";


}

public void onClickListener_cos(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);
    EditTextMsg= editText.getText().toString(); 
    doubleEditTextMsg=Double.parseDouble(EditTextMsg);//degree

    toRadian_doubleEditTextMsg=Math.toRadians(doubleEditTextMsg);

    after_cos =Math.cos(toRadian_doubleEditTextMsg);

    editText.setText(after_cos.toString());

    EditTextMsg=editText.getText().toString();
    result=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

    result_mul=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

    result_div=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);


    sum="";


}

public void onClickListener_tan(View v)
{
    vibrator.vibrate(30);

    EditTextMsg= editText.getText().toString(); 
    doubleEditTextMsg=Double.parseDouble(EditTextMsg);//degree

    toRadian_doubleEditTextMsg=Math.toRadians(doubleEditTextMsg);

    after_tan =Math.tan(toRadian_doubleEditTextMsg);

    editText.setText(after_tan.toString());

    EditTextMsg=editText.getText().toString();
    result=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

    result_mul=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

    result_div=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);


    sum="";
}
public void onClickListener_log(View v)
{

    vibrator.vibrate(30);

   EditTextMsg= editText.getText().toString(); 
   doubleEditTextMsg=Double.parseDouble(EditTextMsg);//degree

   after_log =Math.log10(doubleEditTextMsg);

   editText.setText(after_log.toString());

   EditTextMsg=editText.getText().toString();
   result=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

   result_mul=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);

   result_div=Float.parseFloat(EditTextMsg);


   sum="";


}


public void onClickListener_bra1(View v)
{

   vibrator.vibrate(30);


    bra1=(String)button_bra1.getText();

    sum=sum+"(";
    editText.setText(sum);

}

public void onClickListener_bra2(View v)
{



    bra2=(String)button_bra2.getText();

    sum=sum+")";
    editText.setText(sum);
} 




 public void onClickListener_del(View v)
 {
     vibrator.vibrate(30);
     if(sum !="")
     {
         StringBuilder stringBuilder=new StringBuilder(80);

         stringBuilder.append(sum);

         sum=stringBuilder.deleteCharAt(stringBuilder.length()-1).toString();

         editText.setText(sum);
     }

 }

}
```

LogCat

```
03-22 20:34:39.829: D/gralloc_goldfish(1499): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-22 20:34:40.059: I/Choreographer(1499): Skipped 74 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-22 20:34:45.889: D/AndroidRuntime(1499): Shutting down VM
03-22 20:34:45.919: W/dalvikvm(1499): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     ... 11 more
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1425)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1379)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.os.IVibratorService$Stub$Proxy.vibrate(IVibratorService.java:131)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at android.os.SystemVibrator.vibrate(SystemVibrator.java:57)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     at calc.pack.MainActivity.onClickListener4(MainActivity.java:159)
03-22 20:34:46.059: E/AndroidRuntime(1499):     ... 14 more
03-22 20:34:46.509: D/dalvikvm(1499): GC_CONCURRENT freed 121K, 10% free 2659K/2924K, paused    82ms+29ms, total 448ms
03-22 20:34:49.429: I/Process(1499): Sending signal. PID: 1499 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post the logcat. This will show where the Exception happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Requires VIBRATE permission
```

Insert this permission in your manifest to win.

Comment: Thank you that is solve the problem. but now when I click on any button it dosent appear on the edit text and not do any operations!!

Comment: Read again how `onClickListener` works on Android reference, you will find that you need **only one** handler and then a `switch` inside of it to know which view has been clicked and so on. By following good practices your code can be rewritten in about 20 lines. Speaking about your new problem ask a new question because is about a different topic

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your "`Integer`", "`Float`", and "`Double`" variables to primitive "`int`", "`float`", and "`double`" types.

- Because many of these values are uninitialized (i.e. initialized as `null`), I fear that
  use of them in your `onClick...()` functions may be causing a
  `NullPointerException`.
- My other fear is that reading number objects like this:
  "`one=(String)button1.getText();`" may not work, although I haven't
  tested it (why not just set these non-changing values as constant
  `final` values at the class level?).

You will have to implement various basic modifications to your code in order to change the numeric values from Objects to Primitives, but the changes should all be straight forward.

---

*Despite this advice, the best way to determine where the crash is occurring is to view the LogCat output. It will tell you exactly what line of code is crashing. I have assumed that it is in one of your `onClick...()` functions only because you reported that the app crashes whenever a button is pressed.*

Comment: I change that but another problem comes up. It is an error about toString() "cannot invoke tostring() on the primitive type float"

Comment: That is to be expected. Now that you are using a primitive 'float' instead of the object 'Float', you no longer need functions like 'toString()' to get at the data. However, now that you posted the LogCat, I tend to agree with @gpasci. Did you fix the security permission problem in your AndroidManifest.xml as he suggested?

Comment: yes I did but still the buttons not works. just only I click on them and nothing happens